# how to apply double dollar ( $$) for a string variable in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a set like below.

```
php55MajorVersion=5.5
php55MinorVersion=5
php55Dir="${top_build_dir}/php/php-${php55MajorVersion}.${php55MinorVersion}-${ansdkBuild}"

php56MajorVersion=5.6
php56MinorVersion=6
php56Dir="${top_build_dir}/php/php-${php56MajorVersion}.${php56MinorVersion}-${ansdkBuild}"

php70MajorVersion=7.0
php70MinorVersion=4
php70Dir="${top_build_dir}/php/php-${php70MajorVersion}.${php70MinorVersion}-${ansdkBuild}"
```

Then I have the following input

```
phpVersion="php70"
phpMajorVersion="${phpVersion}MajorVersion"
phpMinorVersion="${phpVersion}MinorVersion"
phpDir="${phpVersion}Dir"
```

Now I want to print value associated with phpMajorVersion , which should be 7.0 (how -> phpMajorVersion -> ${phpVersion}MajorVersion -> php70->MajorVersion -> 7.0).

I have tried using $("${phpVersion}MajorVersion"), but  am still getting , php70MajorVersion , but not 7.0 .
Any pointers on this?

Comment: You win the prize for most confusing question

Comment: @lance-java : changed the question description.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want using the getProperty method like this:

```
ext {
    php55MajorVersion=5.5
    php56MajorVersion=5.6
    php70MajorVersion=7.0
    phpVersion="php70"
}

println getProperty("${phpVersion}MajorVersion")
```

I believe it's not possible to achieve this using just braces, another [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977987/2270026) suggests the same.